# Why does the Async Local Storage change in the parent thread if it is modified in a child thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous

I'm using [Async Local Storage](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage) in my Node.js HTTP server to have a store that is unique for each request. My understanding is that when I execute an async function, the child thread, that is, inside the async function, will have a store that is the same as the one in the parent but when the child does any modification to it, the changes do not propagate to the parent.

But I tried it with the following code:

```js
const als = new AsyncLocalStorage<any>();
const wait = (seconds: number) =>
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, seconds * 1000));

als.run(new Map(), async () => {
    als.getStore().set('key', 1);
    console.log('outside', als.getStore().get('key'));
    foo();
    bar();
    await wait(2);
    console.log('outside', als.getStore().get('key'));
});

async function foo(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, _) => {
        console.log('inside foo', als.getStore().get('key'));
        await wait(1);
        als.getStore().set('key', 2);
        console.log('inside foo', als.getStore().get('key'));
        resolve();
    });
}

async function bar(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, _) => {
        console.log('inside bar', als.getStore().get('key'));
        await wait(1);
        als.getStore().set('key', 3);
        console.log('inside bar', als.getStore().get('key'));
        resolve();
    });
}
```

And the console reads:

```
outside 1
inside foo 1
inside bar 1
inside foo 2
inside bar 3
outside 3
```

I would have expected the last line to be `outside 1`. Is my understanding of Async Local Storage wrong?

If so, would it be possible to accomplish what I expect?

Comment: "*when the child does any modification to it, the changes do not propagate to the parent*" - where does that understanding come from? You create only a single `new Map()` that is shared between your functions.

Comment: Btw, [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi - I was sure I read multiple explanations of Async Local Storage in the past claiming such a thing. But now I cannot find any. I'm very confused. Now I don't know why I believe that.
And sure about those weird functions. I wrote foo and bar with the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the context and your mutable store. When a child enters a new context with a new value, that will indeed not affect the context of the parent execution. But in your example, you enter only a single context, and you store a single `new Map()` in it that is shared between the parent and the children. Modifying that map by setting a key-value pair modifies the single `Map` instance that is also shared with the parent.

You probably did not want to use a `Map` at all. Rather, use `enterWith` or `run` to create a new context, and store your counter directly as the context value:

```
const als = new AsyncLocalStorage<any>();
const wait = (seconds: number) =>
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, seconds * 1000));

als.run(1, async () => {
    console.log('outside', als.getStore());
    foo();
    bar();
    await wait(2);
    console.log('outside', als.getStore()); // still 1!
});

async function foo(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('inside foo', als.getStore()); // 1
    await wait(1);
    als.enterWith(2);
    console.log('inside foo', als.getStore()); // now 2
}

async function bar(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('inside bar', als.getStore()); // 1
    als.run(3, async () => {
        await wait(1);
        console.log('inside bar', als.getStore()); // 3 in here
    });
}
```

You'll want to prefer `run()`, as `enterWith()` has the hazard of affecting subsequent function calls if you place it before the first `await` inside an `async function` (try swapping the `await wait(1);` and `als.enterWith(2);` statements in `foo` and see what happens).